# Pass message from DLL to GUI

Tags: vb.net, object, vb.net-2010

I have created an application which consists of 3 Layers: GUI-BLL-DLL. When I am loading a flat file I am doing this in the DLL but I want to show to the user the process through a progress bar in the GUI. So I want to pass the variable LineCounts from the DLL to GUI. I know that I have to use EVENTS, but how. Can someone help me to understant how to implement this event in VB.NET with code example?

Thanks in advance
Elias

Comment: There is no one who can answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into using a BackgroundWorker.  I presume you'll want to use a background thread to import the text file, and report progress intermittently:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: As I wrote my problem is how to pass the message from the Data Layer to GUI through the Business Layer. The Layers are different DLLs (projects).

Comment: Assuming the user initiates the loading process: 1)  Create new instance of BackgroundWorker in the GUI.  Point the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted delegates at whichever GUI functions you want to.  2)  Pass the BackgroundWorker into the Business layer.  Business layer points the DoWork delegate to the Data Layer.  3) Call RunWorkerAsync in business layer;  flat file loading function can now cast the sender to a BackgroundWorker and use that to reportprogress back to the GUI